# Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `bool' Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with a script on Unity2d.
This is the console logs:
"Assets/Scripts/themeswitch.cs(35,19): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to` bool'"
"Assets/Scripts/themeswitch.cs(39,19): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to` bool'"
I've tried to search a problem in this forum, but it was not what I needed. Here is the script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class themeswitch : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject lightbtn;
    public GameObject darkbtn;
    public GameObject lightmode;
    public GameObject darkmode;

    public void darktheme ()
    {
        darkbtn.SetActive(true);
        lightbtn.SetActive(false);
        lightmode.SetActive(false);
        darkmode.SetActive(true);
        Handheld.Vibrate();
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Theme", 1);
    }

    public void lighttheme ()
    {
        darkbtn.SetActive(false);
        lightbtn.SetActive(true);
        lightmode.SetActive(true);
        darkmode.SetActive(false);
        Handheld.Vibrate();
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Theme", 2);
    }

    void Start () 
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Theme", 1)){
            darktheme();
        }

        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Theme", 2)){
            lighttheme();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Help me solve this problem, because i'm new at unity!)
Thanks)

Comment: I'm not going to try guessing which lines are 35 and 39.

Comment: Additionally, the error message is pretty clear about what the issue is. You've provided an integer value where it expects a boolean value. Modify your post to indicate exactly which line is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name says [`PlayerPrefs.GetInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetInt.html) returns an `int`, not a `bool`.

You are using

```
if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Theme", 1))
```

Which has three problems:

- First as said it is not a `bool` but an `int`
- you use it multiple times which is expensive
- you use it both times with different default return values

What you rather want is reading it once

```
var themeIndex = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Theme", 1);
```

where `1` is the **default** value returned if there was no player prefs found with the key `Theme`.

And then do either

```
if(themeIndex == 1)
{
    darktheme ();
}
else if(themeIndex == 2)
{
    lighttheme();
}
else
{
    // What if it is something else?
}
```

Or directly go for a `switch-case`

```
switch (themeIndex)
{
    case 1:
        darktheme();
        break;

    case 2:
        lighttheme();
        break;

    default:
        // What jf it is something else?
}
```

---

Additionally after changing the value you should also save it calling

```
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

otherwise this is only done in `OnApplicationQuit`

Comment: Can you send me the ready script, if it's not hard for you?

Comment: Sorry, now i don't need it, but thanks anyway, i solved this problem by your steps

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Theme", 1)){
            darktheme();
        }
```

`GetInt` obviously return integer and not a boolean value so it can't be used as `if` condition. You need to compare it against some other value.

Assuming that this `GetInt` call returns 1, what you have is

```
  if (1) { ... }
```

This is not a valid `if` statement condition, which must be a `bool` value, so it must evaluate to `false` or `true`.